# count the number of rows with similar columns values

Tags: unix, scripting, awk

Count the number of rows in a files with similar value  in the last column.

```
   1 517904400201116629 ; 26122010 194609 ; 102 ; 10 ; FR ; M ; NA ; 0 ; (ART1-000010) The FR server timed out.
   1 517904400201116630 ; 26122010 194609 ; 101 ; 10 ; FR ; M ; NA ; 0 ; (ART1-000010) The FR server timed out.
   1 517904400201116631 ; 26122010 194609 ; 101 ; 10 ; FR ; M ; NA ; 0 ; (ART1-000010) The FR server timed out.
   1 517904400201256749 ; 26122010 163432 ; 131 ; 18326 ; FR ; H ; COLC9FMT_TLSIMPStationCheckPostSubscr.cpp ; 92 ; Post Subscriber 4187514772 is not valid for this event.
   1 517904400201261167 ; 26122010 170724 ; 131 ; 18326 ; FR ; H ; COLC9FMT_TLSIMPStationCheckPostSubscr.cpp ; 92 ; Post Subscriber 9052695914 is not valid for this event.
   1 517904400201271471 ; 26122010 181943 ; 131 ; 10 ; FR ; M ; NA ; 0 ; (ART1-000010) The FR server timed out.
   1 517905400201757204 ; 26122010 164743 ; 131 ; 18326 ; FR ; H ; COLC9FMT_TLSIMPStationCheckPostSubscr.cpp ; 92 ; Post Subscriber 9052695914 is not valid for this event.
```

The last values column keep changing. I want to add find out the number of  line  having the same last columns value

how to do this using `awk`?

Comment: Isn't it an homework? If yes please add the "homework" tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If columns are separated by one or more space characters:

```
awk '{a[$NF]++} END{for (el in a) print a[el] " lines end with \""el "\""}' file | sort -nr
```

otherwise, you'll have to change the field separator with the option -F